# You can see a lot of me in the city

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Part of me is above us, the other removes paint.

I would say I am pretty tall.
What am I?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are a

> Skyscraper

Part of me is above us,

> Sky

the other removes paint.

> Scraper

I would say I am pretty tall.

> Skyscrapers are very tall usually.

Title

> In many big cities, you will see skyscrapers.